# .copy function showing red and did not accept any value

Tags: android, android-studio

```
private fun mPerformDeletion() {
    when {
        state.mNumber2.isNotBlank() -> 
            state = state.copy(mNumber2 = state.mNumber2.dropLast(1))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `when` should have a condition inside a bracket `()` but you are using `{}`.
Also `when` is not required for single conditional statements, you can use `if`like:

```kotlin
private fun mPerformDeletion() {
    // assuming state is a `var` & is a `data` class
    if (state.mNumber2.isNotBlank()) { 
        state = state.copy(mNumber2 = state.mNumber2.dropLast(1))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that i forgot to mention the "var mNumber2" class as a data class. when i write it " data class " Error is solved.